# ASP.NET MVC view needs to pass selected dropdown and Calendar date to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, insert

I'm attempting to pass a model back to the the controller for mass updates via a stored procedure in the controller. Two key values that need passed back to the controller are the selected dropdown and calendar date from the view. There are fields in the model to store the information, but I can't figure out how to populate the values in the model.

This is the current code:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="addNew">Add New</a>
</div>
<p>
        PlantArea: @Html.DropDownList("PlantArea", " ")
        EntryDate: @Html.TextBox("EntryDate", @DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new { id = "Calendar", @class = "datepicker" })
        <input type="submit" value="Load Daily Entries" />
        <br /> <br />
    </p>
    <table id="dataTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Employee Id</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Status Reason</th>
            <th>HR Comment</th>
        </tr>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var i in Model)
                {
                <tr style="border:1px solid black">
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].EmployeeId)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Preferred_Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Entry_Code, new { @Value = ViewBag.DefaultAttendanceCode })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].HR_Comment)</td>
                    <td>>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].EntryDate, new { @Value = EntryDate})</td>
                    <td>>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[j].Entry_Code, new { @Value = PlantArea })</td>
                    <td>
                        @if (j > 0)
                        {
                            <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change model binding to Tightly coupled.
means you can bind that control to a model value
like @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.entrydate)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.plantarea)

### where both entrydate and plantarea should be a property in model. and place the control in form element and you can get the value in control on submit.

Otherwise put two hidden textbox in UI and populate the dropdown and date value in those hidden field. then use the hidden field to get the value